# Facebook authentication always gives CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED session

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to implement facebook in my app. I have done it couple of times without any issues. However this time I just cannot figure out the reason behind the error.

The Session state always says CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED. I have gone thorugh various SO links which answer this but all talk about missing API key, `launchmode` of my activity being `singleinstance` or worng/ mis-match key hash.

But I must say, I have checked all of them and they do not seem to be the issue.

I have tried:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.jam.app",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

to get the hash key but in vain. I have also tried the keytool way via command prompt.

My manifest file has the API key as well as below.

Manifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I am stuck from last 3days. Somebody please help. Do let me know if any more detail from my end can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, then there should be an exception object attached to your Session.StatusCallback. Log that exception and see what it says. Also, post the code from which you're opening the session.

Answer (score 2):

Can you paste here the full steps and error you're getting in logcat when trying to connect to Facebook?

If your Facebook application is in development mode and you try to use Facebook Login, but the Key Hash doesn't match, the Key Hash from the apk you're using is shown in Logcat together with a Facebook message. After this you can just paste that one in your Facebook Application Dashboard configuration and see if it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Woooow, finally solved it. Couldn't have figured out unless I created a whole new project. I followed this [facebook set-up](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) guide given by facebook themseleves which actually guided me to the solution.

The issue was, I had imported Facebbok as a module and had added it to the module dependency in my `build.gradle` as

`compile ':facebook'`

whereas the doc clearly states that,

*You may need to add **com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:**  to build.gradle dependencies and rebuild.*

and the build.gradle now looks like this

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
```

and bingo it worked. :)

In addition to the above, it is very important that we generate the hash-key using:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                  "com.example.webwerks.facebookintegartiondemoapp",
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

Credits to #Pratik for helping me out. Thanks :)